# how do I hide elements using jQuery from inside a function

Tags: jquery

I have what I think is a pretty simple function.  But the middle .hide and .removeClass are not happening.  Not sure how to resolve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var li = $(".fb-notification-li");
    function showHide(){
        li.delay(11000);
        $('li.open ul').hide();
        $('li.open').removeClass('open');
        li.fadeIn(600);
        li.delay(20000);
        li.fadeOut(600);
    }
 showHide();                                    
});
```

EDIT --

On good advise I added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravenna/GFydL/).  Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ it and then we'll talk.

Comment: when you're targeting `$('li.open')` are you expecting `$('.fb-notification-li.open')` or are you targeting all `<li class="open">` tags?

Comment: Added a fiddle.  Good call.  should have done it out the gate.  Also no, li.open will not be .fb-notification-li.open.  its a diff li.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Question is a little vague, but I'll give it a go:

I've personally had better luck with the `.delay()` function.

- This code will also fix and handle your (potential) scoping problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fb-notification-li").each(function() {

        setTimeout(11000, function() {
            $(this, '.open ul').hide();
            $(this, '.open').removeClass('open');
            $(this).fadeIn(600);
            setTimeout(200000, function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(600);
            })
        });
    });
});
```